# remove the group of rows which have more rows number than certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set, I want to group the same ID and if the rows number in each group is above e.g. 20, that group should be deleted.

for example:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |

so I wanna group them based on the same ID and remove the groups that have more than 4 rows (i.e. the group ID of "1" and "5" should be deleted)

I used this code but I could not fix the limit of e.g. >=4 (actually I have more than ID to groupby as the code below)

```
model = model.set_index([‘ID’,’X’, ‘Y’, ‘Z’,
                         model.groupby ([‘ID’,’X’, ‘Y’, ‘Z’]).cumcount()+1]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
model.columns = model.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}' .format)
model.reset_index(inplace=True)
model = model.drop(['ID'], axis=1)
model
```

the expected result will be:

| ID | A1 | B1 | A2 | B2 | A3 | B3 | A4 | B4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | nan | nan |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: I don't know if there's function that does such a thing directly but `df[pd.merge(df, df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).size(), on=['ID'])['size'] <= 4]` should retain only the data which is part of those groups that you want to keep.

Comment: @Naveed when I add (transform('size') <=4) does not work

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# filter out the rows that exceeds the threshold, here its 4
df2=df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size') <=4]

# create a seq, and then use a pivot to reformat the data
df2=df2.assign(seq=df2.groupby('ID')['ID'].cumcount()+1).pivot(index='ID', columns='seq')

# swap the column  index level and sort , to matched expected output
df2=df2.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

# combine the column level and reset the index
df2.columns=[ (str(col[1]) + str(col[0])) for col in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index()
```

OR little bit condensed

```
df2=df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size') <=4]
df2=(df2.assign(seq=
                df2.groupby('ID')['ID'].cumcount()+1)
     .pivot(index='ID', columns='seq', values=['A','B'])
     .swaplevel(axis=1)
     .sort_index(axis=1))
df2.columns=[ (str(col[1]) + str(col[0])) for col in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index()
```

```
ID  A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  A4  B4
0   2   2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
1   3   2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   4   2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     2.0     1.0
```

Comment: what if I want to groupby more than one column? I used this code before this question, but the point is I could not fix the limit of >=4 in there  "model = model.set_index([‘ID’,’X’, ‘Y’, ‘Z’,
                         model.groupby ([‘ID’,’X’, ‘Y’, ‘Z’]).cumcount()+1]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
model.columns = model.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}' .format)
model.reset_index(inplace=True)
model = model.drop(['ID'], axis=1)

Comment: I added the code that I used before to my above question

Comment: the very first line filters the rows where there are more than 4 for an ID. you can groupby multiple columns in the filter just as well. Does that help?

Comment: @SHAH, i tried the solution on the sample data you shared and I shared the result. you need to check in isolation, what the transform('size'), returns. Based on your groupby, the group size might always be less than 4